# React display a binary image responce doesnt work. The image doest display when an API request is made from a springboot backend

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, react-hooks, material-ui

I would like to save an image to DB and get the image in a forma displayable in a web page using java springboot and react. The get request works but iam stuck on how to consume the request on react. The image isnt displayed only the alt  message.
below is the get method

```
@GetMapping(path = "/get/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId) throws IOException {

        Optional<TrialImage> dbImage = imageRepository.findByUserId(userId);

        if (dbImage.isPresent()) {
            byte[] imageBytes = ImageUtility.decompressImage(dbImage.get().getImage());
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf(dbImage.get().getType()));
            return new ResponseEntity<>(imageBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

below is the react code to consume the responce which is an image

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { Box, Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import { PropertyListToolbar } from '../../Component';
import { useApi } from '../../REST-API/api';

function PropertyFeed() {
  const api = useApi();
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImage = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await api.get(`account/profilePic/get/${7}`, {
          responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        });
        console.log('Response data:', response.data);
        const blob = new Blob([response.data]);
        const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log('Image URL:', imageUrl);
        setImageSrc(imageUrl);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    fetchImage();
  }, [api]);

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Customers | Material Kit</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Box
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: 'background.default',
          minHeight: '100%',
          py: 3,
        }}
      >
        <Container maxWidth={false}>
          <PropertyListToolbar />
          {imageSrc ? (
            <img src={imageSrc} alt = 'hello' style={{ border: '1px solid black' }} onError={(e) => console.log('Error loading image', e)}/>
          ) : (
            <p>Loading image...</p>
          )}
        </Container>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}

export default PropertyFeed;
```

When i make the request in postman the request is a succes and i can view the image. I also tried to log the responce and the image returned on react but i was not able to get to the root cause why the image is not displayed. I expect to view the image as defined in the img tag in the react code. Kindly Help